# How to parse JSON in form below in body

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with one column with JSON format like this:
in one raw `[{"id":"a85916e0-7afb-41a4-af98-4d629cc846d1","role":1}]`
in 2nd raw I have `[{"id":"248f4445-68a2-4747-b7df-2ca0a1e53381","role":1},{"id":"767ca190-1894-4079-8620-502cc17c3d4c","role":2}]`

What I need is to parse records so I will have like id1, role1,id2, role2.

I have tried next, but it's giving me records from JSON one under another and I have to parse all records and to look like below..

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json = (SELECT  TOP 1 members  FROM [IDW].[dbo].[sub_mem])

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (id VARCHAR(50) '$.id',
  role NVARCHAR(2) '$.role'
  )
```

this is what I need to have:

| members |
| --- |
| [{"id":"a85916e0-7afb-41a4-af98-4d629cc846d1","role":1}] |
| [{"id":"248f4445-68a2-4747-b7df-2ca0a1e53381","role":1},{"id":"767ca190-1894-4079-8620-502cc17c3d4c","role":2}] |

after parsing I need this:

| id1 | role1 | id2 | role2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 248f4445-68a2-4747-b7df-2ca0a1e53381 | 1 | 767ca190-1894-4079-8620-502cc17c3d4c | 2 |
| a85916e0-7afb-41a4-af98-4d629cc846d1 | 1 | null | null |

Comment: if you have 3 roles do you need 6 columns? If you have 10 roles 20 columns? If the answer is yes, then you need dynamic SQL. I would, personally, suggest that the normalised result you're currently getting is correct.

Comment: yes I will need 6 column if there are 3 roles, so what I need is in added screen shot., there would be no more then 3 roles.

Comment: Screenshots in of data don't really help. If you want to provide tabular data then do so as tabular `text` or in a markdown table. That image is too small for me to be able to read it and even understand what it's trying to tell me.

Comment: I have added table, hope this is better.

Answer (score 0):

I have used next and worked I think.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##json1;
GO
CREATE TABLE ##json1( members NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL);
SELECT members INTO ##json1 FROM [IDW].[dbo].[sub_mem]

SELECT * FROM ##json1
SELECT    members
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[0].id')AS id
     ,JSON_VALUE(members,'$[0].role')AS role
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[1].id') AS id1
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[1].role') AS role1
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[2].id') AS id2
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[2].role') AS role2
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[3].id') AS id3
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[3].role') AS role3
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[4].id') AS id4
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[4].role') AS role4
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[5].id') AS id5
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[5].role') AS role5
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[6].id') AS id6
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[6].role') AS role6
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[7].id') AS id7
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[7].role') AS role7
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[8].id') AS id8
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[8].role') AS role8
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[9].id') AS id9
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[9].role') AS role9
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[10].id') AS id10
     ,JSON_VALUE(members, '$[10].role') AS role10
FROM ##json1
where ISJSON(members)=1

DROP TABLE ##json1;
```